# How to debug or trace Angular bindings in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm just starting with development of asp.net core application with Angular using Visual Studio 2017. I'm examining the concept of binding, however, I noticed that there is no support for misspelled properties neither I have any intellisense when trying to bind to property within my html template file, which is extremely error prone.

Once binding is missed, I just don't see the expected content in the browser. What I'd expect is at least some kind of warning/error on the browser's console (well... I just moved from WPF to web apps). Is there any way to improve this experience when using VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about Visual Studio itself, but Visual Studio Code has an extension (among many other useful ones) called [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) that provides intellisense and other useful features for templates.